# C++ method with variable arguments (...) reporting incorrect arg values

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I'm having trouble getting variable arguments to pass properly to a method - the method is intended to select a random value within a weighted distribution and return the index of the selected result.

An example usage would be:

```
int pickupType = randomManager->ByWeights( 3, 0.60f, 0.20f, 0.20f );
switch( pickupType ) {
    // ... pickupType should be 0 to 2, which we can then branch on
}
```

The function is defined as follows:

```
#include <cstdarg>

int RandomManager::ByWeights( int weightCount, ... ) {

    va_list argList;

    // Get the total of all weights
    va_start( argList, weightCount );
    float weightTotal = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < weightCount; i++ ) {
        weightTotal += va_arg( argList, float );
    }
    va_end( argList );

    // Roll a number in that range
    // ... (further processing - problem occurs above)
}
```

When I run it in the debugger, the call to `va_arg( argList, float )` is returning garbage values `( 2.0, 1.77499998, -1.08420217e-019 )`, rather than the values passed in `( 0.60f, 0.20f, 0.20f )`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can tell I'm following the spec exactly. I've been using http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/ as a reference.

Comment: Are you using C++11? If so, you should replace that with a type safe variadic template. I don't see any problems in here, though.

Comment: Eww, var-args always makes me ill.  So many ways it can fail sliently yet spectacularlly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a variadic function, float parameters will be converted to doubles. Try

```
weightTotal += va_arg( argList, double );
```

Comment: The things you forget after getting used to variadic templates. C can be so underhanded sometimes :/

Comment: Thanks - wasn't aware of the double conversion, that solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `float` is promoted to `double` when it is passed through `...`

so your loop should be

```
for ( int i = 0; i < weightCount; i++ ) {
    weightTotal += va_arg( argList, double );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c++ this is not really the correct way to do things anymore. Variadic templates are better than variable args (which are from c). Heres a better example of a variadic sum I did for class a while ago.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace cs540 {
    template <typename T>
    const T & sum(const T & v) {
        return v;
    }

    template <typename T, typename T2, typename ... Ts>
    T sum(const T & v, const T2 & w, const Ts & ... params) {
        return sum(w+v,params...);
    }
}

int main() {
    using namespace cs540;
    using namespace std;
    cout << sum(1.1,2,3,4,6,8,9,1.1) << endl;
}
```

Variadic templates are types safe and produce more readable error free code imo.

Comment: Also longer-  since it's a runtime template, its going to have to create multiple versions, one for each size, isn't it?  If so that's a reason why va_args should still sometimes be used.  EDIT:  bleh, I said run time but meant compile time.  Keeping it because the follow on comments were confused by me.

Comment: @GabeSechan, It creates one definition for each different type of call so as to make overloads for what you need and nothing more. This all happens at compile-time.

Comment: True, but I would think that most functions requiring variadic argument numbers should be simple, for more complex ones you should be using an array at a certain point.

Comment: I meant compile time.  SO it bloats the size of the binary, which is an issue in some situations.  Particularly embedded apps.  This is cleaner syntax, but I'm not sure if I'd implement a printf this way on an embedded system-  you'd end up with a lot of code if you call that function in different ways.

Comment: I wouldn't use c++ on an embedded system

Comment: even though you can compile pure c with a c++ compiler look at the difference in size of the two binaries, generally c++'s will be larger with the same code

Comment: I've frequently used C++-- on embedded systems.  Its C++, but you don't touch certain features that bloat code or have bad implementations on a lot of embedded compilers.  Such as exceptions (huge performance hit) and templates (size bloat).  Having classes is generally worth the speed hit from C.

Comment: @GabeSechan, ok, i've never really had experience with embedded systems